# Highly Nested Json to Datagridview1 Vb.net

Tags: json, vb.net, vb.net-2010

```
{
"gstin":null,
"fp":null,
"version":null,
"hash":null,
"b2b":[{
        "ctin":"2sdasdsadaU",
        "inv":[{
                "chksum":"2fdad1538fe0fde4f03124893cced43453dcdddbf73f0bd4b6103b60c66b76cc",
                "inum":"316",
                "idt":"2019-10-18T00:00:00",
                "val":62235.0,
                "pos":"24",
                "rchrg":"N",
                "inv_typ":"R",
                "itms":[{
                        "num":1,
                        "itm_det":{
                                "rt":5.0,
                                "txval":59271.75,
                                "camt":1481.79,
                                "samt":1481.79,
                                "csamt":0.0
                                },
                        "itc":null
                        }]
                }]
    },
    {
        "ctin":"24sdasdadZU",
        "inv":[{
                "chksum":"2fdad1538fe0fde4f03124893cced43453dcdddbf73f0bd4b6103b60c66b76cc",
                "inum":"316",
                "idt":"2019-10-18T00:00:00",
                "val":62235.0,
                "pos":"24",
                "rchrg":"N",
                "inv_typ":"R",
                "itms":[{
                        "num":1,
                        "itm_det":{
                                "rt":5.0,
                                "txval":59271.75,
                                "camt":1481.79,
                                "samt":1481.79,
                                "csamt":0.0
                                },
                        "itc":null
                        }]
                }]
    }]}
```

This is the Json format what I am trying to get this in Datagridview

its highly nested and I am unable to view it in datagridview using Newtonsoft.

I am able to get it as object of List but using that object as datasource dosen't throw error
or anything

please help me anyone

Answer (score 0):

Class that have been created earlier

```
    Public Class B2b
       Public Property ctin As String
       Public Property inv As List(Of Inv)
    End Class

    Public Class RootObject
       Public Property gstin As Object
       Public Property fp As Object
       Public Property version As Object
       Public Property hash As Object
       Public Property b2b As List(Of B2b)
    End Class ...
```

A List to Datatable Converter for Vb.net

```
Imports System
Imports System.Text
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Reflection

Public Class CreateDataTable
    Public Shared Function ToDataTable(Of T)(ByVal list As IList(Of T)) As DataTable
        Dim table As New DataTable()
        Dim fields() As FieldInfo = GetType(T).GetFields()
        For Each field As FieldInfo In fields
            table.Columns.Add(field.Name, field.FieldType)
        Next
        For Each item As T In list
            Dim row As DataRow = table.NewRow()
            For Each field As FieldInfo In fields
                row(field.Name) = field.GetValue(item)
            Next
            table.Rows.Add(row)
        Next
        Return table
    End Function
End Class
```

Then the function to deserilze json to Datatable

```
Imports System
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Reflection

Private Function Deserilize(ByVal json As String)
            Dim settings = New JsonSerializerSettings With {.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
            .MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore}
            Dim data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of RootObject)(json, settings)
            Dim cl As CreateDataTable = New CreateDataTable()
            Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
            Dim show As b2bdet = New b2bdet()
            Dim showInfo As List(Of b2bdet) = New List(Of b2bdet)()

            For Each value In data.b2b
                For Each inv In value.inv
                    For Each invnum In inv.itms

                        showInfo.Add(New b2bdet With {
                    .CTIN = value.ctin,
                    .inum = inv.inum,
                    .idt = inv.idt,
                    .val = inv.val,
                    .pos = inv.pos,
                    .rchrg = inv.rchrg,
                    .inv_typ = inv.inv_typ,
                    .num = invnum.num,
                    .rt = invnum.itm_det.rt,
                    .taxval = invnum.itm_det.txval,
                    .camt = invnum.itm_det.camt,
                    .samt = invnum.itm_det.samt,
                    .csamt = invnum.itm_det.csamt})
                    Next
                Next
            Next
            dt = cl.ToDataTable(showInfo)
            DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
        End Function
```

Thus i solved the problem